# Hibernate right outer join not supported and could not bring the required results

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

Hibernate right outer join not supported and could not bring the required results

My JPA/hibernate entities are,

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable{
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="categoryList")
    private Set<Coupon> coupon;

    public Set<Coupon> getCoupon() {
        return coupon;
    }

    public void setCoupon(Set<Coupon> coupon) {
        this.coupon = coupon;
    }
}



@Entity
public class Coupon implements Serializable{
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Category> categoryList;

    public Set<Category> getCategoryList() {
        return categoryList;
    }

    public void setCategoryList(Set<Category> categoryList) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }
}
```

Now totally 3 tables are created, those are:

**coupon:**

1 10% off on bus booking

4 20% off on bus booking

**category:**
1 bus

2 recharge

**coupon_category_list:**
coupon | category

1 | 1

4 | 1

**I need the categories with coupon count something like,**

1 bus 2

2 recharge 0

I tried below way,

```
@Override
public List<Object[]> searchCategoriesByParms(Category category) {
    List<Category> categoryResultList = new ArrayList<Category>();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Category> categoryRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Category.class);
final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
Join<Coupon,Category> couponEntity = categoryRoot.join("coupon", JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(couponEntity.join("categoryList",JoinType.INNER));
criteriaQuery.groupBy(categoryRoot.get("categoryId"));
List<Object[]> categoryResultLstObjects = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
return categoryResultLstObjects;
}
```

and it generates the below query:

```
select category4_.category_id as category1_1_, category4_.category_desc as category2_1_, category4_.category_image as category3_1_, category4_.category_name as category4_1_, category4_.category_slug as category5_1_ from category category0_ left outer join coupon_category_list coupon1_ on category0_.category_id=coupon1_.category_list_category_id left outer join coupon coupon2_ on coupon1_.coupon_coupon_id=coupon2_.coupon_id inner join coupon_category_list categoryli3_ on coupon2_.coupon_id=categoryli3_.coupon_coupon_id inner join category category4_ on categoryli3_.category_list_category_id=category4_.category_id group by category0_.category_id
```

I tried different combinations of joins in both coupon and categoryList above, but nothing worked out. But the same I modified with right outer join and executed in my mysql workbench and it results the expected result, but hibernate does not support right outer join.

**Working query with right outer join (but hibernate does not support this)**

```
select category4_.category_id as category1_1_, category4_.category_desc as category2_1_, category4_.category_image as category3_1_, category4_.category_name as category4_1_, category4_.category_slug as category5_1_ from category category0_ right outer join coupon_category_list coupon1_ on category0_.category_id=coupon1_.category_list_category_id right outer join coupon coupon2_ on coupon1_.coupon_coupon_id=coupon2_.coupon_id right outer join coupon_category_list categoryli3_ on coupon2_.coupon_id=categoryli3_.coupon_coupon_id right outer join category category4_ on categoryli3_.category_list_category_id=category4_.category_id group by category0_.category_id
```

Can I have some help here ?

Thanks in advance. **I appreciate if i get the help purely with JPA than hibernate implementations.**